# Building Spring Boot from source to contribute

Tags: java, maven, build, spring-boot

I would like to start contibuting to Spring Boot and have checked out all the code but I can't get the source to build. According to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc I should just be able to run
 mvn clean install 
but I get these errors

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 11 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 1359, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 1449, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-parent\pom.xml) has 3 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1359, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1449, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-test:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-parent\pom.xml, line 232, column 15
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-versions:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-versions\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1359, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1449, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-tools\pom.xml) has 3 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1359, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1449, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-test:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-parent\pom.xml, line 232, column 15
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot\pom.xml) has 7 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1359, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1449, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-context:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot\pom.xml, line 27, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-orm:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot\pom.xml, line 177, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-test:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot\pom.xml, line 182, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-web:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot\pom.xml, line 187, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot\pom.xml, line 209, column 15
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\pom.xml) has 12 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1359, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1449, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\pom.xml, line 238, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\pom.xml, line 243, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jmx:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\pom.xml, line 248, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-jms:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\pom.xml, line 253, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-orm:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\pom.xml, line 258, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-tx:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\pom.xml, line 263, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-web:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\pom.xml, line 268, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-websocket:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\pom.xml, line 273, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\pom.xml, line 278, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-test:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\pom.xml, line 480, column 15
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-actuator\pom.xml) has 7 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1359, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1449, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-context:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-actuator\pom.xml, line 39, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-actuator\pom.xml, line 94, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-actuator\pom.xml, line 99, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-actuator\pom.xml, line 104, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-test:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-actuator\pom.xml, line 227, column 15
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docs:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-docs\pom.xml) has 7 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1359, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1449, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docs:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-docs\pom.xml, line 213, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-orm:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docs:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-docs\pom.xml, line 218, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-test:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docs:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-docs\pom.xml, line 223, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-web:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docs:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-docs\pom.xml, line 228, column 15
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docs:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-docs\pom.xml, line 233, column 15
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starters:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-starters\pom.xml) has 3 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1359, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1449, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-test:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-parent\pom.xml, line 232, column 15
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-cli:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-cli\pom.xml) has 3 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1359, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1449, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-test:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-parent\pom.xml, line 232, column 15
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-integration-tests:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-integration-tests\pom.xml) has 3 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1359, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:pom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://nexus.companyname.com/content/repositories/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus.releases has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-dependencies\pom.xml, line 1449, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework:spring-test:jar is missing. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-parent:[unknown-version], C:\dev\workspace\mine\os\spring-boot\spring-boot-parent\pom.xml, line 232, column 15
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Comment: Do you have any suspicious overrides (especially mentioning "companyname") in your M2_HOME/settings.xml? It could be worth trying with a clean local repo: delete (or rename) the M2_HOME/repository/ folder.

Comment: I pulled that project down, and it seemed to run okay for me. I aborted after about 5 minutes though. How long does this thing run before you get the error?

Comment: Straight away. I'll try with a different settings file. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're using Nexus as a Maven proxy and it doesn't have access to Spring Framework and Spring Integration snapshots that Boot currently builds against. You'll need to make https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot available to your Maven build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new settings file, see below, and using the -s option when running mvn clean install worked although I had to skip the tests but it all built

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository>c:/r2_spring</localRepository>
    <interactiveMode/>
    <usePluginRegistry/>
    <offline/>
    <pluginGroups/>
</settings>
```